# Scopes and Queries with Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have found very little about how one can write scopes for polymorphic associations in rails, let alone how to write queries on polymorphic associations.

In the Rails Documentation, I have looked at the [Polymorphic Associations section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), the [Joining Tables section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables), and the [Scopes section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).  I have also done my fair share of googling.

Take this setup for example:

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
end

class Bird < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
end
```

So a `Pet` can be of `animal_type` "Dog", "Cat", or "Bird".

To show all the table structures: here is my **schema.rb**:

```
create_table "birds", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "cats", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "killed_mice"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

create_table "dogs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.boolean  "sits"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "pets", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "animal_id"
  t.string   "animal_type"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

I then went ahead and made some records:

```
Dog.create(sits: false)
Dog.create(sits: true)
Dog.create(sits: true) #Dog record that will not be tied to a pet
Cat.create(killed_mice: 2)
Cat.create(killed_mice: 15)
Cat.create(killed_mice: 15) #Cat record that will not be tied to a pet
Bird.create
```

And then I went and made some `pet` records:

```
Pet.create(name: 'dog1', animal_id: 1, animal_type: "Dog")
Pet.create(name: 'dog2', animal_id: 2, animal_type: "Dog")
Pet.create(name: 'cat1', animal_id: 1, animal_type: "Cat")
Pet.create(name: 'cat2', animal_id: 2, animal_type: "Cat")
Pet.create(name: 'bird1', animal_id: 1, animal_type: "Bird")
```

And that is the setup!  Now the tough part: I want to create some scopes on the `Pet` model which dig into the polymorphic associations.

Here are some scopes I would like to write:

- Give me all the `Pets` of animal_type == "Dog" that can sit
- Give me all the `Pets` of animal_type == "Cat" that have killed at least 10 mice
- Give me all the `Pets` that are NOT both animal_type "Dog" and cannot sit.  (In other words: Give me all the pets: all of them: except for dogs that cannot sit)

So in my `Pet` model I would want to put my scopes in there:

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true

  scope :sitting_dogs, -> {#query goes here}
  scope :killer_cats, -> {#query goes here}
  scope :remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit, -> {#query goes here} #only removes pet records of dogs that cannot sit. All other pet records are returned
end
```

I am finding it pretty tough to write these scopes.

Some stuff I found online makes it look like you can only write these scopes with raw SQL.  I am wondering if it is possible to use the Hash syntax for these scopes instead.

Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing previous answers and playing around with it: here is what I got to work.

*(Note that `Pet.remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit` returns an array.  This class method is readable but has the drawback of being slow due to `N + 1`.  Any suggestions for fixing that would be greatly appreciated.)*

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
  scope :sits, -> {where(sits: true)}
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
  scope :killer, ->{ where("killed_mice >= ?", 10) }
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true

  scope :by_type, ->(type) {where(animal_type: type)}
  scope :by_dogs, -> {by_type("Dog") }
  scope :by_cats, -> {by_type("Cat") }

  def self.sitting_dogs
    all.by_dogs
       .joins("INNER JOIN dogs on animal_type = 'Dog' and animal_id = dogs.id")
       .merge(Dog.sits)
  end

  def self.killer_cats
    all.by_cats
       .joins("INNER JOIN cats on animal_type = 'Cat' and animal_id = cats.id")
       .merge(Cat.killer)
  end

  # returns an Array not Pet::ActiveRecord_Relation
  # slow due to N + 1
  def self.remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit
    all.reject{|pet| pet.animal_type == "Dog"  && !pet.animal.sits}
  end
end
```

Comment: `self.remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit` could be made faster by using an include on `animal`.  Try `all.includes(:animal).reject{|pet| pet.animal_type == "Dog"  && !pet.animal.sits}`

Comment: note its subtle but when you hit the ".reject" portion you're actually dropping to ruby and leaving SQL behind, hence why its slow. You could chain AREL scopes and stay in SQL, e.g. by_dogs.where(sits: false) should be equivalent, assuming you have NOT NULL and default false set on boolean column in db. IIRC, I may be wrong as I'm going off the top of my head, but the ".all" is implied and unnecessary when you're chaining AREL scopes as long as you have a scope present.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add these scopes to the relevant individual models eg:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
  scope :sits, ->{ where(sits: true) }
end
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
  scope :natural_born_killer, ->{ where("killed_mice >= ?", 10) }
end
```

if you then need them on the main Pet model, you can just add them as methods eg:

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true

  def sitting_dogs
    where(:animal => Dog.sits.all)
  end
  def killer_cats
    where(:animal => Cat.natural_born_killer.all)
  end
end
```

etc

Your complicated case is just all pets minus some that are also sitting dogs.

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true
  scope :sits, ->{ where(sits: true) }

  def sitting_dogs
    where(:animal => Dog.sits.all)
  end

  # There's probably a nicer way than this - but it'll be functional
  def remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit
    where.not(:id => sitting_dogs.pluck(:id)).all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The tough part is what I really care about are the `Pet` records.  I want to take some collection of pet records and filter them based on the scopes.

Comment: Yes - that's what I've got it doing now... you are filtering the pets based on the scopes.

Comment: Note: not tested on real examples... you may need to fiddle with them to get hem working.

Note: you can also use scope-merging.

Comment: My main point is that you don't necessarily need scopes on the Pet model to do what you re asking.

Comment: would your `sitting_dogs` method be a class method instead of an instance method?  Also: I wasn't aware that you could write a scope like you did with the `sits` scope.  It is interesting because you can't call that `sits` scope on the `Pet` class.  Instead it looks like a convenience scope which you actually need to use within the `sitting_dogs` method.

Comment: Yeah, sitting_dogs would be a class method :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree of having individual scopes for sitting dogs and killer cats. A scope could be introduced for Pet to filter them by animal_type.

Here's my version:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
  scope :sits, ->{ where(sits: true) }
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
  scope :killer, ->{ where("killed_mice >= ?", 10) }
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true
  scope :by_type, -> { |type| where(animal_type: type) }
  scope :sitting_dogs, -> { by_type("Dog").sits }
  scope :killer_cats, -> { by_type("Cat").killer }
  scope :remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit, -> { reject{|pet| pet.animal_type == "Dog" && !pet.animal.sits} }
end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!  It looks great, though unfortunately it isn't working for me.  It comes up with the following error when using the `remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit` scope:  `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'reject'`

Comment: It looks like one needs to specify within the scope `all.reject...` in order for it to work, though I am not sure why.

Comment: I also noticed that your `remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit` scope returns an array as opposed to an ActiveRecord::Relation object.  Thus: it probably shouldn't be a scope since it isn't chainable.  It should perhaps instead be a class method.

Answer (score 1):

Not the complete answer, but here's a way of executing the `remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit` query that returns an AR relation and removes the N + 1.

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :dog, -> { where(pets: { animal_type: 'Dog' }) }, foreign_key: :animal_id

  def self.remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit
    includes(:dog).where.not("pets.animal_type = 'Dog' AND dogs.sits = false").references(:dogs)
  end

  def self.old_remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit
    all.reject{|pet| pet.animal_type == "Dog"  && !pet.animal.sits}
  end
end
```

Using a `belongs_to` on a polymorphic model is a great way of speeding up certain queries, especially if your polymorphic model is limited to a small number of options. You can clean up some of your scoped method on `Pet` as well.

```
  def self.sitting_dogs
    includes(:dog).merge(Dog.sits).references(:dogs)
  end
```

Faster too.

```
irb(main):085:0> puts Benchmark.measure { 1000.times { Pet.remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit } }
  0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.032890)
=> nil

irb(main):087:0> puts Benchmark.measure { 1000.times { Pet.old_remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit } }
  1.610000   0.090000   1.700000 (  1.923665)
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of removing N+1 on `remove_dogs_that_cannot_sit`

```
scope :joins_all -> {
  joins("left join cats on animal_type = 'Cat' and animal_id = cats.id")
  .joins("left join dogs on animal_type = 'Dog' and animal_id = dogs.id")
  .joins("left join birds on animal_type = 'Bird' and animal_id = birds.id")
}

Pet.join_all.where.not("animal_type = 'Dog' and sits = 'f'")
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is like bellow:

```rb
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
  scope :sittable, -> {where(sits: true)}
  scope :dissittable, -> {where.not(sits: true)}
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, as: :animal
  scope :amok, ->{ where("killed_mice >= ?", 10) }
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true

  scope :sitting_dogs, -> do
    joins("INNER JOIN dogs on \
    pets.animal_id = dogs.id and pets.animal_type = \
    'Dog'").merge(Dog.sittable)
  end

  scope :amok_cats, -> do
    joins("INNER JOIN cats on \
    pets.animal_id = cats.id and pets.animal_type = \
    'Cat'").merge(Cat.amok)
  end

   scope :can_sit_dogs, -> do
    joins("INNER JOIN dogs on \
    pets.animal_id = dogs.id and pets.animal_type = \
    'Dog'").merge(Dog.dissittable)
  end
end
```

Besides, `scope` name is more inclined to `adjective` rather than a `noun`. So, I use `sittable` `dissitable` `amok` instead of `sits` `killer`.

If you are familiar with [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack), you can also it for search based on the [issue](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/421)

Wish helped you.